# If $(f, g)$ is a Galois connection between two bounded lattices, then if $T$ is an ideal we have $f^{-1}(T)$ is an ideal

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, lattice-orders, galois-connections

Let $\mathcal{I}(L)\:$ and $\mathcal{I}(N)\:$ be the ideal lattices of the bounded lattices $L$ and $N$ and let $(f, g)$ be a Galois connection between $L$ and $N$, then show that $\:\forall \:\: T \in \mathcal{I}(N)\,\,$ we have$\,\,\, f^{-1}(T) \in \mathcal{I}(L)$ (so that, it is well defined) and that $f^{-1}(T) = \downarrow g(T)$.

Showing that $f^{-1}(T)$ is a down set is quite easy: $\:\:\:u\in f^{-1}(T)\iff f(u)\in T\iff \exists v\in T\:$s.t.$\:\:f(u)\le v\iff\exists v\in T\:\:$s.t.$\:\:u\le g(v)\iff u\in\,\downarrow g(T)$.

Any idea about how to see that it is actually an ideal? I mean, that $\forall \: u, v \in f^{-1}(T)$ we have $u \vee v \in f^{-1}(T)$.

Comment: Simply note that $f(u \lor v) = f(u) \lor f(v)$ since $f$ is the left adjoint. Similarly, $f(0) = 0$.

Comment: @amrsa the definition I have is: $\forall x \in L$, $\forall y \in N$ then $x \le g(y) \iff f(x) \le y$. Yes, it is easy to show that $f$ and $g$ with this definition are order-preserving maps, but is it enough to conclude that they preserve the $\vee$?

Comment: @amrsa $u, v \in f^{-1}(T)$, then $f(u), f(v) \in T$ and since $T$ is an ideal $ f(u) \vee f(v) \in T$, by the prop. 7.31 $f(u \vee v) \in T$ so $u \vee v \in f^{-1}(T)$

Comment: @amrsa I can use that result by taking $S = \{x, y \}$ with $x \le y$ and it follows by the fact that $x \le y$ then $x\vee y = \bigvee \{x, y \} = y$. But I will write a proper proof by editing the topic :)